# How to transform a Cauchy-Euler equation into a constant coefficients equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have doubts with a problem that goes like this:

> Let's consider the second order linear differential equation
>
> $ y''(x)+R(x)·y'+S(x)·y=Q(x) $
>
> a) How must the change of variable $z = z(x)$ be so that the equation
> is transformed into one of constant coefficients?
>
> b) Apply the above result to solve the equation:
>
> $ y''(x)+(1+4e^{x})·y'+3e^{2x}·y=e^{2(x+e^{x})} $

I understand what the problem ask I don't know at all how to do it. I even wonder if the statement is right because the condition I get it's a bit abstract.

It's a Cauchy-Euler differential equation, so that:

$$ \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {dy}{dz}· \frac {dz}{dx} = \dot yz'$$

$$ \frac {d^2 y}{dx^2} = ... = \ddot{y}z'^{2}+ \dot yz'' $$

And the differential equation turns to:

$$ \ddot{y}z'^{2}+ \dot yz'' + R(x)·\dot y z' + S(x)y = Q(x) $$

$$ \ddot{y}z'^{2}+ \dot y (z'' + R(x)z') + S(x)y = Q(x) $$

If the equation should transformed into a constant coefficients equation, I think it means:

$$ z'' + R(x)z' = K $$

But I don'tknow what to do from here..

I supposse (in case this result is fine) I can't make K=0 (because it's just a special case) but this is the only value that let me develop a little but more this condition.

Please, anybody know whether this result is right or it has some errors?
How could I solve the problem please? (Not solve it completely, of course. Just a tip to let me continue doing it).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ddot{y}z'^{2}+ \dot y (z'' + R(x)z') + S(x)y =0$$
For this DE to be a constant DE you need:
$$ \dfrac {S(x)}{z'^2}=c_1$$
And:
$$\dfrac {z'' + R(x)z'}{z'^2}=c_2$$
Too many equations. So there must be some relation between $R(x)$ and $S(x)$.

The differential equation;
$$y''(x)+R(x)·y'+S(x)·y=0$$
has no known solution. We can only solve it for some particular functions $R,S$.

Comment: I'm agree with you Aryadeva but I needed some "support" in this way. Thanks for your observations and results.

Comment: You're welcome @cooper